# mysql .net connector throws "Illegal characters in path"

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am building an asp.net app using mysql and EF (database first).

MySQL 5.7.19
Connector/NET 6.9.9

On my first call to the DB, the mysql connector throws an "Illegal characters in path" exception

Other applications on this machine work fine.  The same application on another developers machine works fine.

This doesn't appear to be a connection string problem.  The path that it's throwing the error on is c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe -ap \"DefaultAppPool" - which is of course not a valid path, it's the command line for the app pool that the asp.net app is running in.

And here's the callstack:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(string path, bool checkAdditional)    Unknown
```

> mscorlib.dll!System.IO.Path.GetFileName(string path)    Unknown
>       MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs.ProgramName.get()   Unknown
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SetConnectAttrs()    Unknown
>       MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate(bool reset) Unknown
>       MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()   Unknown
>       MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() Unknown
>       MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)   Unknown
>       MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection() Unknown
>       MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()   Unknown
>       MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()    Unknown
>       MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() Unknown
>       MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()    Unknown
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher.Dispatch(System.Data.Common.DbConnection target, System.Action operation, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionInterceptionContext interceptionContext, System.Action executing, System.Action executed) Unknown
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    Unknown
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()    Unknown
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(bool shouldMonitorTransactions)  Unknown
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(System.Func func, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, bool startLocalTransaction, bool releaseConnectionOnSuccess) Unknown
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery.GetResults.AnonymousMethod__5()    Unknown
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery.GetResults(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.MergeOption? forMergeOption)    Unknown
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator.AnonymousMethod__0()    Unknown
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator.MoveNext()  Unknown

Answer (score 0):

Quatation is an illegal character in the path:

```
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe -ap \"DefaultAppPool
                                          ^
```

Simply you can check it buy trying to create a file, or directory with `"` in its name

Comment: Yes, but I don't create this string, this is deep down in the mysql connector/driver stack.  The question is why is the mysql connector trying to  call Path.GetFilename on the above string?  And how do I work around it?

Comment: @DavidWGray - did you get anywhere with this - I'm seeing the same behaviour?

Comment: @Graeme Wilson - yes and no.  I found a really old and unfixed issue in the mysql bug database.  But it turns out that this exception is caught correctly so there is some weird interaction with the VS debugger where you can't run past a first chance exception.  I've been turning off exceptions in the debugger until I get past the intial connection which has unblocked me.

Comment: @DavidWGray we were only seeing the exception in PerfView but several times a minute in our production environment.  It looks like it's fixed in MySQL.Data 6.10.6 so we're going to try upgrading the client.  It has a dependency on .NET 4.5.2 so we have a bit of work to do in upgrading from our current .NET 4.0 DAL.